# Nivo slider css drop down menu conflict

Tags: css, menu, slider, nivo-slider

I am working on a website that I am trying to add nivo slider to. The issue that I am having is that the slider covers up the css drop down menu and I don't see the directional arrows within the menu.

When I added z-index:-50 to the .nivoSlider line in the nivo-slider.css file the menu worked as it should, by not hiding behind the slider, but I still do not have the navigation arrows, and now the navigation arrows within the actual slider (left or right) are visible but don't work.

The link to see these issues is [here](http://www.clarkbrands.com/gallery2.php).

Any help that is suggested will be appreciated.
Thanks, Joe

Comment: I just went through your website. Instead of changing the z-index of slider change the zindex of .dropmenu li ul li a. I tried it it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first remove z-index from `.nivoSlider`. Second and most important part - you have structure in menu like this:

```
<ul id="nav-one" class="dropmenu css-only">
<li><a style="border-left:1px solid #CCCCCC; padding-left:23px; padding-right:23px;" href="index.php">Home</a></li>

<li><a href="company.php">Company</a>
    <ul class="SomeNewClass">
    <li><a href="history.php">History</a></li>
    <li><a href="markets.php">Markets</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="licensee-advisory-board.php">Licensee Advisory Board</a></li>
    <li><a href="copyright-notice.php">Copyright Notice</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
<li><a href="branding.php">Branding</a>
    <ul class="SomeNewClass">
    <li><a href="graphics.php">Graphics</a></li>
    <li><a href="signs.php">Signs</a></li>
    <li><a href="paint.php">Paint</a></li>
    <li><a href="dispenser-doorSkins.php">Dispenser DoorSkins</a></li>
    <li><a href="dispenser-overlays.php">Dispenser Overlays</a></li>
    <li><a href="image-manual.php">Image Manual</a></li>
    <li><a href="image-evaluation-form.php">Image Evaluation Form</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="payments-processing.php">Payments Processing</a>
    <ul class="SomeNewClass">
    <li><a href="fleet-card.php">Fleet Card</a></li>
    <li><a href="echoSat.php">EchoSat</a></li>
    <li><a href="PCI-compliance.php">PCI Compliance</a></li>
    <li><a href="transnational.php">TransNational</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
....
....
....
```

As you can see, i've added class named `.SomeNewClass`. Put this class in all positions like i show you in example and then put this into your CSS

```
.SomeNewClass
{
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. I was wondering if you could help me with just one more. If you look at any other page on the same website here: http://www.clarkbrands.com/index.php you can see that the drop down menu has navigation arrows within it. If you look at the page that has the nivo slider: http://www.clarkbrands.com/gallery2.php the drop down menu has no arrows.

Again, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: :) You forgot to add <span class="arrow"></span> inside every <a> element with drop-down options in <li> tag :) (Note for future: I recommend you to use awesomeness of "Inspect element" in Google Chrome and "Firebug" in Firefox. It will save your life :) )

Comment: I don't understand, can you give me an example.

Comment: In pages with arrows in menu, structure of menu is like this <li><a>**some link text**<span class="arrow"><span><a/></li>. So page that has Nivo slider doesn't have that <span class="arrow"></span> at all. You forgot to add that line of code.

Comment: It is my pleasure to help others because others help me ;) Play around with that Inspect Element option in Google Chrome (right click on any element you going to inspect), it's really an indispensable tool in the work. Good luck ;)